# Management of threads in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have created 2 threads in my android app but they don't work :(.

```
final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                // @Override
                public void run() {
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
                    Log.e("mediafile", mediaFile+"");
                }
            };
            t1.start();

            final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                // @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, ModificationActivity.class);
                    Log.e("le chemin de la photo", "" + mediaFile);
                    myIntent.putExtra("imagePath", ""+mediaFile);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            };
            try {
                t1.join();
                t2.start();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My variable is always at null when I start my intent because the first thread is not finished.

I hope you can help me :D

Thanks in advance to all

This is the log :

> 11-05 14:29:59.936 18216-18216/com.mcm.citadium I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 72 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 11-05 14:30:05.140 18216-18387/com.mcm.citadium E/mediafile﹕ null 11-05 14:30:05.148 18216-18389/com.mcm.citadium E/le chemin de la photo﹕ null 11-05 14:30:05.652 18216-18216/com.mcm.citadium E/fin de photoCallback﹕ /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20131105_143005.jpg

Comment: Which variable is null? It doesn't look like the first thread is setting any variables.

Comment: Concurrency in Java is not trivial.  If you are having these kinds of problems, I highly recommend reading all that you can on the subject before attempting to make a real app that using multi-threading.  This is a good starting point ->  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: `t1.join()` blocks until thread `t1` get terminated, your problem is not a thread thing.

Comment: Post the actual stack trace. I suspect you're getting the exception inside `t1`, at your log statement, and that the problem has nothing to do with the threads.

Comment: it's not the first time that i use a thread in java, but it's the first time that i've this problem.

Comment: Where is `mediafile` set?  What is its definition?

Comment: actually, I dont even know why you're even using threads in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you don't need to create any threads to capture image - you can run `camera.takePicture` on main thread safely - it will handle its job in another thread anyway (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29)).

So, for example you could trigger picture-taking activity in your button `onClick` handler :

```
        shootButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
            }
        });
```

Your `photoCallback` would then look something like :

```
    Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // generate file path for new picture
            String fileName = "myPicture.jpg";
            String mediafile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
               .getCanonicalPath() + "/mydir/" + fileName;

            // launching new activity to modify picture
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,
                ModificationActivity.class);
            Log.e("le chemin de la photo", "" + mediaFile);
            myIntent.putExtra("imagePath", ""+mediaFile);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Ok so i think i search hard when it's easy :( . Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Handler]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
to schedule the two thread.

Some examples :

http://androidexample.com/Thread_With_Handlers_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=58&aaid=83

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/

Or [AsyncTask]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html which is almost equal to " Handler + Thread + Message + ThreadPool "

Some examples :

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 0):

Why is the starting of t2 inside the try-catch? I think if you simply place both starts outside of the try-catch, and then join both threads in it, this should work.

```
t1.start();
t2.start();

try {
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```